# Definition affine kac moody algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, kac-moody-algebras

Take $\mathfrak{g}$ a simple Lie algebra and $k$ the Killing form of $\mathfrak{g}$. Now I found two definitions of affine Kac Moody algebra associated to $\mathfrak{g}$.

The first: a one-dimensional central extension of $\mathfrak{g}\otimes\mathbb{C}((t))$

The second: a one-dimensional central extension of $\mathfrak{g}\otimes\mathbb{C}(t)$

In both of them, if $A$ is a central element, the bracket is defined by $[x \otimes f, y \otimes h]=[x,y]\otimes fh + k(x,y)Res(fh')A.$

I'd like to know if them are isomorphic lie algebras and in case some reference to study them on.

Comment: The third one from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_Lie_algebra). An affine Kac-Moody algebra is a  central extension of the infinite-dimensional Lie algebra ${\displaystyle {\mathfrak {g}}\otimes \mathbb {\mathbb {C} } [t,t^{-1}]} $, with one-dimensional center ${\displaystyle \mathbb {\mathbb {C} } c.} $ What are your links for your definitions?

Comment: A small correction. The above definition is for an *affine Lie algebra*. The corresponding affine Kac-Moody algebra is defined as a semidirect product by adding an extra generator $d$ that satisfies $[d, A] = δ(A)$.